Pyspark connector slow during joins
I'm building an application that allows me to use pyspark to combine an oracle and a cassandra table. The cassandra table's count is in a scale of 100s of millions with the oracle one at a few 1000.
Doing a join across oracle and cassandra table takes me 3 minutes on a good system. Looking over the execution plans also revealed cassandra filters as empty tho the join is on cassandra's main partition keys. Can you explain why this could be the case? I just put a for loop for each combination of parition keys and filtered in cassandra and that seemed faster.
Similarly, I wanted to do a df_cassandra.filter(col('column') in [list of 200 unique values]) and that took way too long to complete.
Can you help me understand why?
Filtering by each element works. Join fails
Filter in [] takes too long
